# Как развернуть символы в строке после двоеточия?

Tags: delphi, строки

Как поменять строки, текстового файла, чтобы символы в них шли в обратном порядке после символа двоеточие?

Пример текста до обработки:

> Test:**Результат1**

После обработки текст должен быть во в таком виде:

> Test:**1татьлузеР**

А в моем коде переворачиваются строки целиком, а не после символа двоеточие:

> **1татьлузеР:tseT**

Делаю так:

```
var f1,f2:TextFile;
  s:string;
  i,n:integer;
  c: char;
...
while not Eof(f1) do
begin
  Readln(f1,s);

  n:=length(s);
  for i:=1 to n div 2 do
   begin
    c:=s[i];
    s[i]:=s[n-i+1];
    s[n-i+1]:=c;
   end;
Writeln(f2,s);
```

Знаю что нужно добавить в код проверку - от какого символа, но как добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while not Eof(f1) do 
begin
  ReadLn(f1, s);

  n := Length(s);
  colonIndex := Pos(':', s);
  if colonIndex > 0 then
  begin
    for i := (colonIndex + 1) to colonIndex + ((n - colonIndex) div 2) do
    begin
      c := s[i];
      s[i] := s[n - (i - colonIndex) + 1];
      s[n - (i - colonIndex) + 1] := c;
    end;
  end;

  WriteLn(f2, s);
end;
```

Comment: Igor, Delphi пишет вот такое сообщение: Undeclared identifier: 'colonIndex'. Я так поняла это какой то модуль нужно подключить в Delphi ?

Comment: @Татьяна добавьте `colonIndex: integer;` в секцию `var`